# pygame rectangles drawn in loop scroll across screen

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

Here is my full code:

```
 import pygame
pygame.init()

i = 0
x = 0

# Define the colors we will use in RGB format
BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE  = (  0,   0, 255)
GREEN = (  0, 255,   0)
RED   = (255,   0,   0)

# Set the height and width of the screen
size = [600, 300]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("Test")

#Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while not done:
    clock.tick(10)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done=True

    screen.fill(WHITE)

    for x in range(x, x+100, 10):
       pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, [x, 0, 10, 10], 1)

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

10 squares are drawn but they scroll across the window to the right and i dont know why. Is there any way I could stop this?

Thanks.

I realise now that it is not about the rectangle loop, but i have changed that to what has been suggested anyway.

Comment: What do you mean across the screen? Because from what I can see in the code snippet you've provided, you are drawing 10 rectangle along the x axis. This too is across the screen. :) Also the `x = x+1` is incorrect unless you are aiming for `x = x+2` which is basically what happens since `for x in range(10)` does increase `x` with one every iteration and adding an extra increase statement increases `x` by 2. You don't need the `i` (in a range you can set the step and just increase the limit to 100).

Comment: By across the screen i mean that 10 rectangles along the x axis and then all 10 are moving across the screen. You are right about the x + 1, thanks, but i dont get what you mean about not needing the i (im probably just being stupid, sorry) @rbaleksandar

Comment: Are you doing some sort of a translation before that? I don't have experience with PyGame but in my experience with OpenGL for example if something moves across the screen when you don't want it to in 99.9% of the cases it's because you have applied some transformation that is not reset during each iteration of the main loop and it just adds to it's previous state leading to an "infinite" transformation (in your case - translation).

Comment: Try posting a minimal working example because as of right now there is nothing wrong with the code you have provided. I just installed `pygame` and used it and there is no moving across the screen whatsoever. It's something outside the loop that is causing you headaches.

Comment: I meant `for x in range(0, 100, 10): pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, [x, 0, 10, 10], 1)` and assign the `x` as the x coordinate of your rectangle's starting point.

Comment: I have added the full code with the new loop @rbaleksandar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you have added more code I see where the problem is coming from and it's just as I suspected - you are doing a static translation the incorrect way namely you use the `x` (which you have defined outside your main loop) in your `for x in range(x, x+100, 10):`.

If you add a `print(x)` statement inside your `for`-loop you will be able to see that the `x` gets bigger and bigger, and bigger...This is perfect for adding dynamics to your scene but my guess is (based on your question) that you want to add 10 static rectangles to your scene.

In order to do that you need to reset your `x` every single time a new iteration of the `while` loop begins:

```
while not done:
    clock.tick(10)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done=True

    screen.fill(WHITE)

    # Every single iteration of the while loop will first reset the x to its initial value
    # You can make x be any value you want your set of rectangles to start from
    x = 0

    # Now start adding up to x's initial value
    for x in range(x, x+100, 10):
      pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, [x, 0, 10, 10], 1)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

You can also omit the definition of `x` as a variable outside the `for` loop if you won't be using it to change the x coordinate where your first rectangle will start from and replace the `range(x, x+100, 10)` with `range(CONST, CONST+100, 10)` where `CONST` is a given value such as 0, 100, 1000 etc.

Comment: That looks kind of right, but I need to check it before I accept. If you reset the x to 0 every time wouldn't it just redraw the rectangle in the same place? @rbaleksander

Comment: Yes, the drawing will always start from the same place and the remaining 9 rectangles will follow based on the `range` you've defined. If you want the rectangles to move (because from its current state one can only conclude you want the rectangles to remain in place), change your question.

Comment: Oh, I get you now, sorry. Thanks.

Comment: So at the end this is what you want - static and not dynamic rectangles?

Comment: Yes, my question was probably badly worded

Comment: Okay. Glad it got resolved. Btw since you are programming a game you will sooner or later have to add collision detection (I think). If you want to move stuff around don't forget about that!

Comment: Yep I think I will, thanks for all the help @rbaleksandar

Answer (score -1):

Every time your for loop runs the range is incremented, because the `x` is persistent. If you remove the `x=0`, reset it inside the `while`, or use a different variable in the `for` loop I think it will work.

```
x=0
while not done:

    for x in range(x, x+100, 10):
       pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, [x, 0, 10, 10], 1)
```

Comment: @rbaleksandar obviously didn't read the text. The code I showed wasn't intended to work, it's intended to show the problem without all the extraneous code in the way.